# How to know if an EditText has changed before save the data?

Tags: java, android, forms, android-edittext

I have a Profile's form with some `EditText` like the name, address, city and so on. And I have a `Button` to save this data once you press it.

So I would like to know how can I check if there have been changes before make my app connect with the database and update it.

I've thought using a `TextChangedListener()` with some `boolean` on the `onTextChanged()` or `afterTextChanged()`, but I don't know exactly how to do that.

Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

---

I´ve tried the code below and it works for me. I have this right now:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {

TextView done_btn;
EditText local_court;
boolean hasChanges = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    done_btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_profile_btn);
    local_court = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_local_court);

    done_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(checkChanges()) {
                //saveChanges();
                finish();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your changes have been saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

public boolean checkChanges() {
        local_court.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                hasChanges = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        return hasChanges;
    }
}
```

I guess I should make the same with the other `EditText`.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Please post your code so far you have tried.

Comment: While the events may let you know that someone changed a value, they could have changed it back to the original. If you store the original values and compare the values in *EditText* before saving, you could make sure that they didn't change the value back to the original.

Comment: If you have an object, you can keep en memory the previos object and compare with the new (with hashcode an equals), if it is different some has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is just to check if something has changed at all, just check the current EditText value to what was before.

But if you want to know if the text has been touched, even reverted back to original, do as below.

```
EditText etext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTxt);

etext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                                             @Override
                                             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                                                       int start, int before,
                                                                       int count) {
                                                 //Set your boolean here to true
                                             }

                                             @Override
                                             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,
                                                                           int start, int count,
                                                                           int after) {
                                             }

                                             @Override
                                             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                             }
                                         }

    );
```

Comment: Holly... it was easier that I thought. Thank you very much. And sorry for the poor question.